# Iterate an object with reverse sorted keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I know my question title can be confusing (I'm aware object properties don't have an order) since I'm already proposing a solution with it, so to avoid creating an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), let me first explain my goal:

I need to render *N* tables of words grouped by word length and (this is the tricky thing) **ordered by length in descending order** . Something like:

```
Words with length 4
===================
abcd | other fields
abce | other fields 
abcf | other fields

Words with length 3
===================
abc  | other fields
abd  | other fields
abe  | other fields

Words with length 2
===================
...
```

I'm getting my list of words from an API without any grouping, so what I'm doing right now is:

```
let grouped = {};
// Assume words is an Array of words of multiple lengths
words.forEach(w => {
    if (typeof grouped[w.length] === 'undefined')
        grouped[w.length] = [];
    grouped[w.length].push({'word': w}); 
    // Pushing an object cause of other calculated and not rellevant fields
});
```

Of course, when I render this `grouped` words (I'm using Vue.js)...

```
<WordsTable 
    v-for="(group, length) in grouped"
    :words="group"
    :word-length="length"
/>
```

*I use the `word-length` prop to render the table's header saying* Words with length N.

Everything works but I get the tables in **ascending** order (and, again, I'm aware this might be a coincidence because there's no order in objects). So the real question is, can anybody figure out a way so that Vue iterates my `grouped` object with descending sorted keys?

*Note: There might not be words of some specific lengths, so maybe `Object.keys(grouped)` is `[3,4,7,9,10]`*

**UPDATE:**

A commenter suggests using an Array instead of an Object for `grouped`. I already tried and it's true that might be slightly better but doesn't completely solve the problem.

If `grouped` is an array, I can reverse it:

```
<WordsTable 
    v-for="(group, length) in grouped.reverse()"
    ...
/>
```

But in this case, indexes are lost and can no longer be used to render the table's header title.

Comment: You could store the words in an array instead of an object. Replace `let grouped = {}` by `let grouped = []`

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work either. Let me update my question with more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a computed property that sorts your object keys in a descending order:

```
sortedGroupKeys() { 
    return Object.keys( group ).sort( ( a , b ) => b - a ); 
}
```

then you can loop though it.

```
<WordsTable 
    v-for="(key in sortedGroupKeys)"
    :words="group[ key ]"
    :word-length="key"
/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Iterate over a sorted list of the keys.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("WordsTable",{
  props: ["words", "length"],
  template: `
    <table>
      <caption>Words of length {{length}}</caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="word in words"><td>{{word}}</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    words: [
      "hello", "apple", "mister", "wut", "phenomenal", "and", "vue", "four", "word"
    ]
  },
  computed:{
    grouped() {
      return this.words.reduce((groups, word) => {
        (groups[word.length] = groups[word.length] || []).push(word)
        return groups
      }, {})
    },
    sortedDesc(){
      return Object.keys(this.grouped).sort((a,b) => b - a)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
caption {
 text-align: left;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 10em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <words-table v-for="length in sortedDesc" :key="length" :words="grouped[length]" :length="length"></words-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Bert. Your solution works perfectly but I'm going to chose Tarik's because it doesn't require another level of iteration (oh, now I see you edited to remove this extra `v-for`). Anyway, I'm picking your `reduce()` based grouping! Thanks for your time/help!

Comment: @JordiNebot his answer is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, it uses exactly the same idea but IMHO he applied it better to my current component in the first place. You edited later to remove the extra `v-for`. I mean, this is not a competition, and I'm thankful to both of you, but at the time I accepted an answer, his suited better my code.

Comment: @JordiNebot there are two loops either way (the component has to loop over the words). Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We can reverse the object using *slice()* and *reverse()*.

Here the code I've applied to reverse the object:

```
v-for="edge in $static.posts.edges.slice().reverse()"
```